# Is there a way to read UNCOMMITTED rows only in dapper?

Tags: c#, transactions, dapper, isolation-level, dbconnection

I have already set the isolation level to `IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted` is there an option to fetch uncommitted data only? Without manually altering Stored Procs to be called?

Below is the script for fetching uncommitted data only:

```
SELECT * FROM Users.[User]
 EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM Users.[User] WITH (READCOMMITTED, READPAST)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dapper doesn't really have anything to do with this. There are two options here:

- if your SQL flavor (backend-dependent) allows you to express this: great
- if your ADO.NET connection/transaction (provider-dependent) supports this: great

Dapper simply doesn't have any relation to either. It sits on top of the provider, and the calling code provides the syntax.